# When comparing a users answer to randomly generated code, the program thinks that they are always the same no matter what is input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am building a game that generates a random code for the user to remember and then asks them to input it back. When checking to see if the users input is correct, the script always thinks that the input was correct despite what I have inputed. I think it may be an issues as a result of passing variables incorrectly because the generated code variable is on a seperate script. I have tried multiple methods of comparing these scripts but no matter what I get the same result.

Here the random code is generated and I assign a variable to it to be called in another script.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;

public class RandomAlphaNumerical : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text StringText;
    public string question;
    
    

   public void Start()
    {
        
     char[] letters = "qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm1234567890!@#$%^&*()" .ToCharArray();
        System.Random r = new System.Random();
        string randomString = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            randomString += letters[r.Next(0, 45)].ToString();
        }

        question = randomString;

        StringText.text = randomString;

    }   
}
```

Here is where the strings are compared. No matter what I try it will always change to scene 4 the 'win screen'.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;

public class Answer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string input;
    public string correctprompt;

    

    public void Start()
    {
        GameObject.Find("RandomAlphanumerical").GetComponent<RandomAlphaNumerical>().question = correctprompt;

    }

    public void ReadStringInput(string s)
    {
        input = s;

        Console.WriteLine(input);
        
        

      if (input == correctprompt)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
        }

      if (input != correctprompt)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(5);
        }


    }
}
```

I am worried that the issue may also be in the unity gameobjects so if there is an effective way to do this with worrying about gameobjects for each script such that would be the best. However I really will take any advice you have, Im completely stuck.

Thanks for reading, any help will be greatly appreciated.

P.S Please comment if there is anymore infomation you might need to solve this issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, [please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), you can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68871485/edit) your post to fix it.

Comment: Easier to follow if you post the code directly in your question instead :)

Comment: Hint - you never _set_ `correctprompt`.

Comment: @mjwills Im sorry I dont understand. Wouldnt defining it as a public string be enough?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `question` be equal to `correctanswer`

```
GameObject.Find("RandomAlphanumerical").GetComponent<RandomAlphaNumerical>().question = correctprompt;
```

But you want it to be the other way around instead.

```
correctprompt = GameObject.Find("RandomAlphanumerical").GetComponent<RandomAlphaNumerical>().question = correctprompt;
```

It's also a good idea to grab the value when you need it. Since now you are both generating it and storing it in separate Start() and you don't know the order order in which these are executed.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System;

public class Answer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string input;
    //public string correctprompt;
    
    private RandomAlphaNumerical _randomAlphaNumerical;

    public void Start()
    {
        // Get a reference to the script with the random code
        _randomAlphaNumerical = GameObject.Find("RandomAlphanumerical").GetComponent<RandomAlphaNumerical>();

    }

    public void ReadStringInput(string s)
    {
        input = s;
        // Grab the value here instead
        string correctprompt = _randomAlphaNumerical.question;
        
        // Log both values to see what they are
        Console.WriteLine("Input: " + input);
        Console.WriteLine("Correct answer: " + correctprompt);           

        if (input == correctprompt)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(4);
        }

        if (input != correctprompt)
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(5);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Im afraid when I tried to implement your revisions I found that I was getting the oppostie problem, it would find the input to be wrong no matter what. This leads me to believe that I may have a problem within the unity editor but I can't seem to work it out. If you have any more advice that would be greatly appreciated but thank you for your time regardless.

Comment: What output you are getting? What are the values of `input` and `correctprompt` in `ReadStringInput`. If you give an example of what you are getting I can more easily figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I wasnt getting outputs for some reason so I change the Console.WriteLine to a Debug.Log and then notice that the ouput for the randomly generated code was different to one I had been shown, suggesting that it was regenerating the code when it was checking for the right answer.

Comment: Yes, you need to check if it has generated the code before checking against it and/or storing it somewhere else. Now you are generating and saving the code in two separate start functions, and you do not know which will run first. You could change the code generator to be inside `Awake()` instead of `Start()` to be sure the that the code exist before using it in the other script. There are many ways to solve this depending on your needs, and my suggestion is just one of them. Here you can read a bit on execution order of theses functions https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

Comment: Ive tried your suggestion of Awake() it is still regenerating. I tried putting the code generator in a if function to check what scene was currently active and that didnt work. Any other advice?

Comment: No idea, maybe update question with a screenshot of your unity scene. Where the game objects in the scene can be seen. Not sure what you mean by "then notice that the ouput for the randomly generated code was different to one I had been shown". If the code keeps changing it means that you probably have the script which generates the code attached to more than one game object in the scene??